# Repeat first line on whole text file using python

Tags: python, csv, io

I am making a Twitter sentiment analysis. After cleaning the tweets, when I try to write tweets into `.txt` file from `.csv` it writes only first tweets in text file and repeats until the end. Consider the following code

```
f = open('PanamaCase.csv', 'r')
with f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    i=0
    for row in reader:
        row=str(row['Tweets'])

        #print(type(row))
        print(clean(row))
        txt = open('cleanedTweets.txt','w')
        #line = 0
        with txt:
            reader2 = csv.DictReader(f)
            for line in reader2:
                txt.write(clean(row) + "\n")
```

Comment: You want to open a text file, read the first line until you hit `\n` and close it again?

Comment: no, i want to write in the text file basically \n is used for to get 1 tweet and change the line! hope you understand

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing right now? What is the problem?

Comment: it write only first tweet in file and repeat that tweet in whole file

Comment: Are you sure about the indentation of your snipped? Seems like the line `txt = open(...` should be on the same level as the first open statement.

Comment: How does your csv look like

Comment: my csv have only one column!

Comment: "my csv have only one column! " which is a strange CSV file then. Not sure what you mean by CSV to TXT conversion then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are reading the input file twice in your code (or actually 1 + once for each line).

I suggest to try:

```
f = open('PanamaCase.csv', 'r')
with f:
    txt = open('cleanedTweets.txt','w')
    with txt:
       for row in reader:
          row=str(row['Tweets'])
          print(clean(row))
          txt.write(clean(row) + "\n")
```